# HikariCP - Multiple datasources, only primary datasource's pool started (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

So, I've configured my spring boot application to handle multiple datasource everything is good, but I noticed that when I launch the application, the primary datasource's pool is started but not the others, only when they are needed (which sometimes results in nullpointer...)

```
2020-03-05 15:34:02.478  INFO 11172 --- [           main] be.MyApp.ESPI.EspiApplication           : 

Starting EspiApplication on BESVC-HQ2000928 with PID 11172 (C:\Users\...\Documents\MyApp\Others\ESPI\ESPI\target\classes started by ... in C:\Users\...\Documents\MyApp\Others\ESPI\ESPI)
2020-03-05 15:34:02.483  INFO 11172 --- [           main] be.MyApp.ESPI.EspiApplication           : The following profiles are active: dev
2020-03-05 15:34:03.149  INFO 11172 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-03-05 15:34:03.233  INFO 11172 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 65ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-03-05 15:34:03.811  INFO 11172 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-03-05 15:34:04.433  INFO 11172 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-03-05 15:34:04.444  INFO 11172 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-03-05 15:34:04.444  INFO 11172 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2020-03-05 15:34:04.603  INFO 11172 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-03-05 15:34:04.603  INFO 11172 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2047 ms
2020-03-05 15:34:04.761  WARN 11172 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : FirstPool - maxLifetime is less than 30000ms, setting to default 1800000ms.
2020-03-05 15:34:04.761  INFO 11172 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : FirstPool - Starting...
2020-03-05 15:34:05.095  INFO 11172 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : FirstPool - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getNetworkTimeout()I)
2020-03-05 15:34:05.099  INFO 11172 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : FirstPool - Start completed.
2020-03-05 15:34:05.159  INFO 11172 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-03-05 15:34:05.243  INFO 11172 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.10.Final}
2020-03-05 15:34:05.414  INFO 11172 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-03-05 15:34:05.554  INFO 11172 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
2020-03-05 15:34:06.519  INFO 11172 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-03-05 15:34:06.526  INFO 11172 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-05 15:34:06.853  WARN 11172 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-03-05 15:34:06.947  INFO 11172 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-05 15:34:07.115  INFO 11172 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-03-05 15:34:07.116  INFO 11172 --- [           main] be.myapp.ESPI.EspiApplication           : Started EspiApplication in 5.135 seconds (JVM running for 5.744)
2020-03-05 15:34:17.044  INFO 11172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-05 15:34:17.044  INFO 11172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-03-05 15:34:17.052  INFO 11172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
2020-03-05 15:34:17.087  WARN 11172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : SecondPool- maxLifetime is less than 30000ms, setting to default 1800000ms.
2020-03-05 15:34:17.087  INFO 11172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : SecondPool- Starting...
2020-03-05 15:34:17.176  INFO 11172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : SecondPool- Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getNetworkTimeout()I)
2020-03-05 15:34:17.178  INFO 11172 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : SecondPool- Start completed.
```

As you can see FirstPool is started. Spring Application starts. Then, only when needed, the SecondPool is started... I wonder how I can force the pool to start before the application starts ?

EDIT : 
My properties file are like this :

```
# DataSource definitions :

first.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@*a host*
first.datasource.username=user1
first.datasource.password=xxxxxxxxx
first.datasource.poolName=FirstPool
first.datasource.maximumPoolSize=100
first.datasource.maxLifetime=10000

second.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@*another host*
second.datasource.username=user2
second.datasource.password=xxxxxxxxx
second.datasource.poolName=SecondPool
second.datasource.maximumPoolSize=100
second.datasource.maxLifetime=10000
```

Second part :

```
# Profile definition
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@

# JPA definitions
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database=oracle

# DataSource
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.dataSourceClassName=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.dataSourceProperties.implicitCachingEnabled=true
spring.datasource.hikari.dataSourceProperties.fastConnectionFailoverEnabled=true

# Oracle specifics
oracle.net.tns_admin=${ORACLE_HOME}/NETWORK/ADMIN
```

The configuration class that handle the DB Configuration :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties", "classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"})
@Primary
public class DBConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "FirstDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("first.datasource")
    @Primary
    public HikariDataSource FirstDataSource() {
        return (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "SecondDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("second.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource SecondDataSource() {
        return (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name="FirstTM")
    @Autowired
    @Primary
    DataSourceTransactionManager FirstTM(@Qualifier ("FirstDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txm  = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
        return txm;
    }

    @Bean(name="SecondTM")
    @Autowired
    DataSourceTransactionManager SecondTM(@Qualifier("SecondDataSource") DataSource datasource) {
        DataSourceTransactionManager txm  = new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
        return txm;
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you post your config file code where you are initializing the pool?

Comment: @VishalSharma : Edited to add .properties files and configuration class.

Comment: I had doubt that your Bean might also be Lazy but that's not the case. Hence it should be initialized at the startup only. Can you put breakpoints in your methods and see if it hits all the bean creation at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer.

So, first, the dataSources are all created, BUT, the pool attached to it are not created until asked. So the idea is to force their initialization when starting the application.

This can be achieved like this (see [How to configure hikari pool for eager initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908309/how-to-configure-hikari-pool-for-eager-initialization) ):

You can use an [`ApplicationLoader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html) and get a connection at startup:

```
@Component
public class HikariLoader implements ApplicationRunner {

  private final HikariDataSource hikariDataSource;

  @Autowired
  public HikariLoader(HikariDataSource hikariDataSource) {
    this.hikariDataSource = hikariDataSource;
  }

  @Autowired
  public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws SQLException {
    hikariDataSource.getConnection();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well that might work, but you are leaking a connection!. Also you should be programming to interface `DataSource` and not the concrete implementation.

Comment: Thanks, what would you suggest ? Close the connection right after opening it ? I'm open to have a cleaner solution.

Comment: That is one thing at least. However specifying `minimumIdle` for hte pools should trigger early startup as it will pre-fill the pool (make it lower then the maximum pool size!). If you configure this with idle checking things should automatically start.

Comment: I just try, by removing the call .getConnection from the run and changing the properties to set a minimumIdle. Got the same issue, the pool is not started until called. And the manually (through properties) setting the minimumIdle is discouraged from hikariCP. By default it is set to MaximumPoolSize property.

Comment: The problem with that is if the min and max are equal there is no idle checking done whilst connections are checked out. Just checked the code, if you use the default `HikariDataSource` constructor, pool creation is delated, when using the one passing in a `HikariConfig` the pool is started eagerly.

Comment: I have a similar issue at the moment and need to check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach, It works for me with both data sources.

```
 first.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc-url
        first.datasource.username=username
        first.datasource.password=password
        .
        .
        .
        .
        =================== In Java Configuration File ==================
        
        @Primary
       @Bean(name = "firstDataSource")
            @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "first.datasource")
            public DataSource dataSource() {
                return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
            }
        
    
    @Primary
            @Bean(name = "firstEntityManagerFactory")
            public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                    @Qualifier("firstDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
                Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
                props.put("spring.jpa.database-platform",  "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect");
        .
        .
        .
        
                return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.first.entity").persistenceUnit("firstDB")
                        .properties(props)
                        .build();
            }
    
        @Primary
            @Bean(name = "firstTransactionManager")
            public PlatformTransactionManager firstTransactionManager(
                    @Qualifier("firstEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory firstEntityManagerFactory) {
                return new JpaTransactionManager(firstEntityManagerFactory);
            }
    
    second.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc-url
    second.datasource.username=username
    second.datasource.password=password
    .
    .
    .
    .
    =================== In Java Configuration File ==================
    
       @Bean(name = "secondDataSource")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "second.datasource")
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }
    
        @Bean(name = "secondEntityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                @Qualifier("secondDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
            Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
            props.put("spring.jpa.database-platform",  "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect");
    .
    .
    .
    
            return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.second.entity").persistenceUnit("secondDB")
                    .properties(props)
                    .build();
        }
    
        @Bean(name = "secondTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager secondTransactionManager(
                @Qualifier("secondEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory secondEntityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(secondEntityManagerFactory);
        }
```